# R: Passing a list of data frames to a sqldf function

Tags: r, list, function, sqldf

I have a list with some data frames

```
myList <- list("A"=A, "B"=B)
```

I need to pass each data frame to a function which will return another list of data frames after its inner processing through a sql query.

```
myFunction <- function(x){

    inner.processing.1 <- sqldf(sprintf("SELECT 
                                        // do something
                                    FROM '%s'", x$A))


    inner.processing.2 <- sqldf(sprintf("SELECT 
                                        // do something
                                    FROM '%s'", x$B))

    inner.list <- list("C"=inner.processing.1,"D"=inner.processing.2)
    return(inner.list)

}

myFunction(myList)
```

The x$A, x$B approach gives the error  "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". How do I fix this?

Comment: The error sure seems like you are passing a non-list element to the function. Are you really sure this example represents what you are really doing? If i define `sqldf <- function(...) paste("query", ...)` and `myList <- list("A"=1:3, "B"=1:3)`, this code runs without error for me.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use x$A as an argument to `sprintf`. That seems unlikely to be valid to me. Seems to be an error on the same level as a typo.

Comment: In that case, how can I use a data frame (which is a list item) in a sql query? As an example, sqldf("SELECT * FROM myList$A") doesn't work. It says no such table: myList$A.

Comment: If you know the name at the time you write your function then hard code it as in my last comment or if you only know the name at run time then use the code in the answer to insert the name into the sql statement.

Comment: For future questions please ensure any code you post is complete.  The inputs A and B and the sql statements were not defined.  Also the library statements are missing.  The objective is that anyone else can simply copy your code to their R session to run it.  See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with the code:

- in the SQL statements `from` needs to be followed by the *name* of a data frame but the code is attempting to pass a data frame itself rather than its name
- the input data frames are in a list which is not accessible to `sqldf` unless they are put in an environment and the `sqldf` statement is told which environment to look in

Using the built in data frame `BOD` as an example:

```
f <- function(L) { # L is named list of 2 data frames
  e <- list2env(L)
  list(
    C = fn$sqldf("select * from `names(L)[1]`", envir = e),
    D = fn$sqldf("select * from `names(L)[2]`", envir = e)
  )
}

library(sqldf)
f(list(A = BOD, B = 2 * BOD))
```

giving:

```
$C
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8

$D
  Time demand
1    2   16.6
2    4   20.6
3    6   38.0
4    8   32.0
5   10   31.2
6   14   39.6
```

**Note:** The above assumes that you only know the names of the data frames at run time.  If you knew them at the time the function is written then they could simply be hard coded:

```
f2 <- function(L) { # L is named list of 2 data frames
  e <- list2env(L)
  list(
    C = sqldf("select * from A", envir = e),
    D = sqldf("select * from B", envir = e)
  )
}

library(sqldf)
f2(list(A = BOD, B = 2 * BOD))
```

giving the same result as shown previously.

Comment: It worked! Is there a way I can use the list item name instead of position? Something like names(L)$A instead of names(L)[1]?

Comment: Have moved my comments to a Note in the answer.  Note that `names(L)$A `makes no sense. `names(L)` is a plain vector of names. It does not itself have names.   You either know the name in advance or you don't.  If you do hard code it and if you don't insert it at run time.

Comment: Hi! A follow up scenario, what if in my example, the first list item A was also a list.(in there, they have no item names). How would I write the SELECT FROM statement to indicate the list inside the list?

Comment: Your data frames must have names if you want to use sqldf.  Add names if there are no names existing.

Comment: So, if I give names to the list items within a list item, how does that change for the sql code? In the earlier example `select * from A` was when A was a list item in L. If A is also a list and I want to pick A1 (first item of A) , is it `SELECT * FROM A1`, or something in the lines of A$A1?

Comment: You need to put the data frames into an environment, use their names in the sql statement and specify the environment using envir= .  Suggest you read the section on environments in Hadley's Advanced R (which is online and free).